# Unknown process using high amount of CPU

Tags: cpu, cpu-load

My CPU usage is reporting as running at 100%

Running top -i I get

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
3696734 root      20   0 2492344   6456   3504 S  1143   0.0   8:17.16 .system3d
3586276 myUser     20   0  477744  47756  34520 S   5.6   0.1   1:10.26 xfce4-taskmanag
3534870 myUser     20   0  307504 163248  53768 S   3.7   0.2   2:14.20 Xtigervnc
```

I have no idea what .system3d is and can't find it when running as root user, when I kill it it restarts.

Any ideas what this process is or why it would be using up so much of my CPU?

Comment: That looks suspicious. Do a `sudo lsof | grep 3696734` to find out what it's doing, before you kill it.

Comment: Pretty sure it's doing some sort of mining or other activities and then posting to an IP. If I kill it, it returns not sure how I find the source and kill it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, i suggested doing a `lsof`, to start with.